# jObject.Parse error WP8

Tags: json, windows-phone-8, json.net

I have a problem with JSON.NET. 
In particular, in my app I access to a service that returns the following JSON: {"auth": "false"} 
I can easily do the call with RestSharp, but if in the callback function i try to use the call JObject.Parse (response.Content) I am returned an unhandled exception. Below is my call back function:

```csharp
private void CallBack (IRestResponse response) 
{
    try 
    {
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) 
        {
            string content = response.Content.ToString (); 
            Jobject json = JObject.Parse (response.Content); // This statement creates the problem 
        } 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {} 
}
```

I want to clarify that in the case of instruction that creates the problem (jobject json = JObject.Parse (response.Content)) to debug i can not get into the callback function, so I can not debug. 
Do you have any suggestions? this thing had ever happened to me and I am very surprised.

Comment: It would really help if you could tell us what the exception is.  I notice you're catching the exception but then throwing it away (empty catch block).  If you can't debug the callback, can you log the exception?

Comment: Thanks, i solved by deleting the folder and reinstalling the package...Strange but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The line should be like this.

```csharp
JObject json = JObject.Parse(content);
```

The parameter for the JObject.Parse() should be a string. So the JSON string should be passed to it.

Comment: I'm sorry, i made a mistake, the variable is already a string. It's possible that the error is because you need put callback in dispatcher?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i solved by deleting the folder and reinstalling the package...Strange but it works.